# MySQL table comparison between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `follow` and `followed`. I want to get all the rows in the `follow` table such that `follow.screen != followed.following_screen_name`.

**follow table**

```
ID    screen_name
-----------------
1      eddie
2      jason
3      omar
4      jonathan
5      jack
```

**followed table**

```
ID    my_screen_name    following_screen_name
-------------------------------------------
1      john                eddie
2      kenny               eddie
3      kenny               omar
4      john                jason
5      john                omar
```

---

**Query I tried which didn't work**

```
SELECT follow.screen_name from follow, followed where followed.my_screen_name='john'
AND follow.screen_name != followed.following_screen_name
```

**Expected results**

```
ID    screen_name 
-----------------
1      jonathan      
2      jack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get this by doing a `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT F.screen_name FROM follow F
LEFT JOIN followed FD
on F.screen_name = FD.my_screen_name
OR F.screen_name = FD.following_screen_name
WHERE FD.my_screen_name IS NULL
and FD.following_screen_name IS NULL
```

Another way is to use `NOT EXISTS`, get all rows that exists in followed and do NOT EXISTS clause to get desired result.

```
SELECT F.screen_name FROM follow F
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM followed FD
  WHERE F.screen_name = FD.my_screen_name
  OR F.screen_name = FD.following_screen_name
)
```

Comment: +1. The predicate in the WHERE clause of the "outer join" query makes this into an "anti-join" pattern... all rows from `F` along with matching rows from `D`, and then exclude all rows that had a match. (Kudos for pointing out that there are multiple patterns that return the specified resultset.)

Comment: @JohnDoe, you need to replace F.screen_name with John for first condition and replace OR with AND. here is the sql fiddle. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ef0a/5

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to solve this, but common to all is that you need to compare the follow.screen_name to both followed.my_screen_name and followed.following_screen__name.

One way is to use NOT IN with a UNION:

```
select screen_name 
from follow
where screen_name not in (
  select following_screen_name
  from followed 
  where following_screen_name is not null
  union all
  select my_screen_name
  from followed 
  where my_screen_name is not null
  )
```

While this approach is nice for clarity, it may not be as good for performance as using a left join or not exists.

Comment: We need to be careful that the subquery doesn't return any NULL values. (We may have a guarantee that the columns are NOT NULL, but absent that guarantee, in the more general case, we'd need to include add `col IS NOT NULL` predicates in the subquery.)

Answer (score 0):

A nice place to pick up mysql syntax and logic is [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).
But try this code, it selects every row where the screen_name is not identical to anything produced in the next two queries:

```
SELECT * from follow WHERE screen_name
not in (select screen_name from followed)
AND not in (select followed_screen_name from followed);
```

The last two queries would look this and the WHERE filters all of the rows out with screen names identical to the fields below.

```
my_screen_name    following_screen_name
-------------------------------------
john              eddie
kenny             eddie
kenny             omar
john              jason
john              omar
```

Comment: Note that if either of the subqueries returns a NULL value, the outer query will return zero rows. (The expression `col NOT IN ('a',NULL,...)` will never return TRUE, because that's equivalent to `col <> NULL AND col <> 'a' ...`.